What is the name for the matrix of amplitudes for a bipartite state?
I'm not one for names of things, more concepts. However, when I teach, that creates problems as I can't put a name on something for students to be able to go and find more information. In particular, when you have a bipartite state
$$
|\psi\rangle=\sum_{i,j}c_{ij}|ij\rangle,
$$
consider the matrix of coefficients $C$, comprising elements $c_{ij}$. Does that have a standard name in the field? If not, I'm tempted to use something like "bipartite amplitude matrix" in my lecture notes.

A biadjacency matrix?  This is a $|U|\times|V|$ matrix for a bipartite graph between partitions $U$ and $V$.

It would be nice if there was a good name for this matrix — I don't know how many times I've written "Let $C$ be the matrix for which $\vert\psi\rangle = \operatorname{vec}(C)$," or something along those lines. Referring to it as the "matrixification" of $\vert\psi\rangle$ certainly doesn't roll off the tongue...

"Bipartite amplitude matrix," or maybe just "amplitude matrix" is kind of nice, except that the concept makes perfect sense (and is useful) more generally, when we don't necessarily want to think about the vector entries as amplitudes. Maybe "coordinate matrix"?

Inverse Choi-Jamiołkowski isomorphism of $|\psi\rangle$ ?

"unvectorisation of $|\psi\rangle$"?

There is no standard name for $C$.
